# What is the definition of a limit superior for a set valued mapping?

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

I'm considering a set valued mapping $X(t): \mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the power set. Given a paramater $t \downarrow 0$, I thought I could define the  $\underset{t \downarrow 0}{\limsup} X(t)$ as

$$\underset{t \downarrow 0}{\limsup} X(t) :=  \lim_{t \downarrow 0}\big ( \sup \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \ : \ x \ \text{is a limit point of } X(t) \} \big )$$

This, however, appears to be wrong. I am told that the limit should look something like $\underset{t \downarrow 0}{\limsup} X(t) = X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and I believe my definition gives a single limit point instead. If anyone more familiar with these definitions could help me out I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Often, indicator functions are helpful in this context.  You probably want to look at something like the lim sup of the sequence of indicator functions giving the indicator function of the limit.

Comment: do you have some kind of reference as to how that is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides indicator functions, you can define a lim sup to be
$$\limsup_{t \downarrow 0} X(t)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \forall t \in \mathbb{R}^+, \exists t_1 \in (0,t) s.t.  x \in X(t_1)\}  $$

Comment: is that equivalent to $\limsup_{t_k \downarrow 0}X(t_k) := \bigcap_{k = 0}^{\infty} \bigg(\bigcup_{m = k}^{\infty} X(t_m) \bigg) $ ?

Comment: It is equivalent as long as there are only a countable number of values that $t$ takes.  The one I gave works whether or not this number is countable or not.

Comment: okay, I see the difference. Thanks so much for the help!